# What are the reasons for casting a void pointer?

Tags: c

I'm learning C++ from scratch, and as such I don't have an expert understanding of C. In C++, you can't cast a void pointer to whatever, and I understand the reasons behind that. However, I know that in C, you can. What are the possible reasons for this? It just seems like it's be a huge hole in type safety, which (to me) seems like a bad thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can cast a `void*` to another pointer in *both* languages. Perhaps you meant implicitly.

It's very convenient in C to not have to be explicit about it. In C++ we have templates, so to write generic code there's no need for `void*` casting and whatnot. In C there is no choice. A generic container has to hold `void*` to objects, and it's much easier to repeatedly say `mydata* d = node;` then it is `mydata* d = (mydata*)node;`.

So it's pretty much like you said. In C type safety in general didn't receive as much emphasis as it did in C++, especially when it came to `void*` because it was suppose to be a simple generic pointer to whatever. There's no need for that in C++, so better make it explicit when you're dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the possible reasons for [casting a `void *` pointer in C]?  Isn't this a giant hole in type safety?

It's the only possible way to support polymorphism, aka generic programming.  There's no other way to make, e.g., a generic hash table.  Polymorphism in C is wildly unsafe, but it's the only polymorphism there is.

Be glad that C++ has parametric polymorphism (one of the many functions of templates).

Answer (score 0):

One reason: if you use `sort` to sort an array of structs, and you have a comparison function for the two structs, you'll need to cast the void pointers to pointers to the structs to access members of the struct.