# How should I type cast void *?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

I am learning C. I need to define a function to type cast the value of `void *` to the desired type.  I'm not sure if I fully understand what I need to do.  Here is my attempt. Can someone take a look and let me know if it's correct? If not, how should I fix it? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
void print_type(TYPE a)
{
    void *v_ptr;
    v_ptr = &a;

}
```

Comment: No need of any casting to and from `void *` in `C`..

Comment: @VoidPointer Nomen est omen.

Comment: i am also not quite sure what it is you need to do, could you show the requirement? normally if you want to cast to another type from `void* ptr` to another type you just write `(type)ptr`.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590314/what-are-the-reasons-for-casting-a-void-pointer

Comment: @H2CO3, I just noticed that :)

Answer (score 5):

In C, `void *` is implicitly compatible with any data pointer type. If you have a POSIX implementation, then it's compatible with function pointers as well. There's no need for typecasting; conversely, [it's even considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: +1. I was also thinking about «value of void * to the desired type»... Not sure if just a bad description of a question about converting a pointer to `uintptr_t` or something like that :->

Comment: @VladLazarenko Thanks. Well, if I understood the question well, then this is all what OP is looking for...