# Typecasting a void pointer in a Linked List

Tags: c, arrays, struct, linked-list

I have an array of structs called arrayOfElements and I want them stored ( in better terms pointed to ) in a Linked List so I've malloc'd the arrayOfStrucs

```
arrayOfElements= malloc(4 * sizeof(Element));
```

and then once I have put in all the data in I want to pass it to a function called insert which imports the head of the list and the array of structs

```
LinkedList* insert(LinkedList* head, Element* inArrayOfElements)
```

My issue is that I've been told that the data member in the linked list has to be a void* , thats a hard requirement. So my question is, in the function insert how do I go about making void* data from the linked list

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    void* data
    struct LinkedList* next;
    } LinkedList;
```

point to the imported array of structs?

```
LinkedList* insert(LinkedList* head, Element* inArrayOfElements)
{ 
    LinkedList* insertNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    insertNode->next = head;
    /*WHAT DO I DO HERE TO MAKE void* data point to inArrayOfELements*/
    return insertNode;
}
```

Comment: `insertNode->data = inArrayOfElements`? I'm not sure about this

Comment: `inserNode->data = (void*)inArrayOfElements`. This requirements makes sense, if you will use your linked list to store elements of different types. But then you will need some field to understand what data is in the node. If you store only `Element` pointers, `void*` type requirement is rather strange one.

Comment: Yeah typecasting `(void*)`in this case is better, my bad.

Comment: thanks, I think its because each struc in the array will hold a different data type , so ArrayOfElements[1] could be a int and ArrayOfElements[0] could be a string

Comment: @CrispyCashew, must you use a linked list for this? What type of problem are you solving?

Comment: yeah unfortunately. Just one more t lets say I wanted to print  the the contents of arrayOfElements[1] which I know is a int. How would I do that if its being pointed to in the Linked List

Comment: @RoadRunner actually, typecasting to `void*` is pointless for this in C. Conversion is done automatically in both directions. Your initial command seems correct, though the question isn't exactly crystal clear. I can't tell whether the OP wants to store *each* element in `inArrayOfElements` as a single node in the list (and if so, where's the array size param?), or just a single node with `data` pointing to the base array pointer.

Comment: Yeah thanks @WhozCraig. I guess it's like typecasting `malloc`, where you don't need to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to a void pointer, like this:

```
inserNode->data = (void*)inArrayOfElements;
//                ^ Explicit cast here
```

This requirement makes a lot of sense if you'll be storing multiple types of data in your `data` field of the linked list.

Please note that in C, such a cast is optional and only for readability purposes. Conversion from `Anything*` to `void*` is strictly speaking unnecessary in C. In C++ it wouldn't, and there are downsides to it, as @WhozCraig points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211659/typecasting-a-void-pointer-in-a-linked-list/40212075?noredirect=1#comment67688577_40212075). So pick your poison there.

Comment: Conversion from `AnyObjectType*` to `void*` and back in C is automatic. No cast should be required.

Comment: Not certainly. It also makes it more brittle. If/when conditions change such as the param is no longer a basic pointer type the cast will happily (and unhelpfully) hide the mistake. With C++ it would be mandetory, but in C [there is no need for it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16449344/1322972), and plenty of reasons to avoid it. Given a choice between using, and *not* using, an unnecessary cast, choose the latter.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added a disclaimer to the answer citing your comment. I hope its clearer now.